# Merge two list of TimeRanges into one

Tags: c#

I have a class named `TimeRange` and another `Interval` both have same following structure

```
public class TimeRange
{
   public TimeOfDay start{get; set;}
   public TimeOfDay end{get; set;}
}
```

I have two list

```
List<TimeRange> timeRanges = new List<TimeRange>();
timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(Timespan.FromHours(5), Timespan.FromHours(6)));
timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(Timespan.FromHours(8), Timespan.FromHours(9)));

List<Interval> interval = new List<Interval>();
interval.Add(new Interval(Timespan.FromHours(1), Timespan.FromHours(7)));
interval.Add(new Interval(Timespan.FromHours(10), Timespan.FromHours(15)));
```

I want to merge these lists into one so that final result will contain this

```
Timespan.FromHours(1), Timespan.FromHours(5)
Timespan.FromHours(5), Timespan.FromHours(6)
Timespan.FromHours(6), Timespan.FromHours(7)
Timespan.FromHours(8), Timespan.FromHours(9)
Timespan.FromHours(10), Timespan.FromHours(15)
```

Another case:

```
timeRange.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(9), TimeSpan.FromHours(17))
timeRange.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(17), TimeSpan.FromHours(19))

interval.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(0), TimeSpan.FromHours(4))
interval.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(4), TimeSpan.FromHours(5))
interval.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(5), TimeSpan.FromHours(9))
interval.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(9), TimeSpan.FromHours(10))
interval.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(12), TimeSpan.FromHours(13))
```

Expected Result:

```
Timespan.FromHours(0), Timespan.FromHours(4)
Timespan.FromHours(4), Timespan.FromHours(5)
Timespan.FromHours(5), Timespan.FromHours(9)
Timespan.FromHours(9), Timespan.FromHours(10)
Timespan.FromHours(10), Timespan.FromHours(12)
Timespan.FromHours(12), Timespan.FromHours(13)
Timespan.FromHours(13), Timespan.FromHours(17)
Timespan.FromHours(17), Timespan.FromHours(19)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having two classes that do same job? Why do you need to merge them to one list? What have you tried?

Comment: These two classes represented differently in different domains. I have to merge it to perform some operation on the final list. My issue is that one list can have more elements then other hence couldn't figure out which one to loop over?

Comment: What's the logic in why you have 5 new ranges from 4? Why isn't this 1-5, 6-7, 8-9, 10-15? It could also be 1-5, 5-6, 6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-15 if you wanted each 'sub time span'. What exactly should your final logic be searching for to end up with 5?

Comment: Because 1-7 gets overlapped with 5-6 hence need to be split 1-5, 5-6, 6-7

Comment: Are you looking for a `Dictionary<TimeRange, Interval>`?

Comment: I'm looking for List which combines both list and takes care of overlapped timespans by splitting the actual item in the list

Comment: I tried to generate some code to do what you want King, it may have some problems though. I'll be back later to fix any problems

Answer (score 0):

After realizing I was thinking about this problem in the wrong way I came to an approach that should work in most scenarios. If you come across some data that this doesn't work on please provide it to me and I'll fix it. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TimeRange> timeRanges = new List<TimeRange>();
            timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(TimeSpan.FromHours(2), TimeSpan.FromHours(3)));
            timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(TimeSpan.FromHours(8), TimeSpan.FromHours(9)));
            timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromHours(5)));
            timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(TimeSpan.FromHours(3), TimeSpan.FromHours(6)));

            List<Interval> intervals = new List<Interval>();
            intervals.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromHours(7)));
            intervals.Add(new Interval(TimeSpan.FromHours(10), TimeSpan.FromHours(15)));

            timeRanges.AddRange(intervals.Select(x => new TimeRange(x.start, x.end)));

            timeRanges = TimeRange.ResolveOverlaps(timeRanges);

            timeRanges.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.start} - {x.end}"));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class TimeRange
    {
        public TimeSpan start { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan end { get; set; }

        public TimeRange(TimeSpan st, TimeSpan en)
        {
            start = st;
            end = en;
        }

        public static List<TimeRange> ResolveOverlaps(List<TimeRange> timeRanges)
        {
            var times = new List<TimeSpan>();
            times.AddRange(timeRanges.Select(x => x.start));
            times.AddRange(timeRanges.Select(x => x.end));
            times = times.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Ticks).ToList();

            timeRanges.Clear();
            while (times.Count > 1)
            {
                timeRanges.Add(new TimeRange(times[0], times[1]));
                times.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            return timeRanges;
        }

    }

    public class Interval
    {
        public TimeSpan start { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan end { get; set; }

        public Interval(TimeSpan st, TimeSpan en)
        {
            start = st;
            end = en;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you wentimo for your help. It works in some case, however, it breaks in the new cases I have. Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: I updated my answer to a most robust solution. Let me know if it's still not working for you

Comment: This approach does not seem to be working with the second case I mentioned. Also it restricts the TimeRange and Interval class to only have two property members only.